# How to add Application Insights for existing Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, web-applications, monitoring, azure-application-insights

I have 10 Web Applications in Azure. But I can't configure  Application Insights for them because I haven't saved projects with them. 
When I create new WebApp in VisualStudio - it possible to add  Application Insights for application and publish to Azure.
But when I connect to my  existing Azure WebApp from Visual Studio with FTP URL - I can't add Application Insights for monitoring.
How can I configure Application Insights for monitoring my 10 existing applications? Or is there another way to monitor them?

Comment: Stackoverflow is oriented towards programming Q&A. This question might get more replies at serverfault.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to monitor an already running app in Azure without republishing Microsoft has released a nice tutorial on doing so please find it here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now

also, consider adding application insights to your projects code base for future publishing please have a look at this tutorial provided by Microsoft as well

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net

Hope this will help.